# Is there a built-in C# method to go from an empty string to null value?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

There are many times in which I have an input text, and, if it's empty (if the user didn't type any text, for example), I want to send a null value to the DB query.

I do **not** want to send `String.Empty.` (or `""`).

Thus I find myself doing this a lot:

```
var mySqlValue =  string.IsNullOrEmpty( tbCustomerId.Text)?null:tbCustomerId.Text;
```

This seems ugly to me. .NET gives a lot of other solutions for the opposite scenarios:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace
myProblemVal ?? myDefultVal
```

Is there anything built-in to C# that lets me do this a shorter way, like the opposite direction?

**I know this can be solved by writing my own extension methods and I know how to do that; that's not a solution I'm interested in.**

I'm looking for some code like "`if empty -> null`".

Comment: There's also the following problem: If `.Text` is a property (i.e. a call to a `get` accessor), the first time the getter is called, it may return a long string, say `"John Doe"`. The we get to evaluate the last "component" of the ternary `?:` conditional operator. But this calls the `Text` getter again, and this time it may return `""`. So in priciple you have to take a local variable copy of `Text`. This is not necessary, of course, if you use an extension method.

Comment: If you use an extension method, you can `Trim()` the string first before checking, which is hard to do in the single expression.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there anything built-in to C# that lets me do this a shorter way

No, although I'd argue that what you describe in the question (extension methods) is absolutely fine. And as you describe in the question, in the other direction you have null-coalescing.

Comment: @Royi oh sure, the conditional is a bit ugly there... funny thing, though; I'd say that if you **use `""` to mean `null`**, then there's already a problem - i.e. why are you holding a `""` if you mean `null`? use a `null` to mean `null`, and a `""` to mean `""`, and the problem you are trying to solve ceases to exist

Comment: im not holding `""` - the property `tbCustomer.Text` is `""`...... ( and not null)

Comment: @Royi so why does your database-related code know about what appears to be a UI control (`tbCustomer`)? Meh, no matter. Another approach you could use, if orchestrated more cleanly, would be to have a property on an object: `public bool HasWhatever { get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Whatever);} }` then you can use a conditional on that, i.e. `object val = obj.HasWhatever ? obj.Whatever : DBNull.Value;` - just a thought

Answer (score 36):

You can use an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static string NullIfWhiteSpace(this string value) {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) { return null; }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Which you could use like that:

```
var mySqlValue = tbCustomerId.Text.NullIfWhiteSpace();
```

I don't really know what you imagine by something better than Extension methods. How do you define "better"? Shorter? Using a special keyword? Using rarely used operators to look clever? This is already just a single method call appended to your value, which even works on null values, and the logic you need can't really be expressed in a shorter way than this. Also, I don't know of any special syntax for it.

Comment: i explictly wrote `I know this can be solved by Extension methods - and i know how to do it..` - is there anything better

Comment: oops, didn't see that part :) But i don't see a more elegant way.

Comment: Even though he said he knew, this is probably the best way instead of a whole bunch if ifs

Answer (score 10):

Declare your own static method:

```
public static string NullIfEmpty(string value)
{
  return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? null : value;
}
```

Doing

`MyHelper.NullIfEmpty(value)` is not uglier than a call to a static method of string type... And it seems cleaner than writing `string.IsNullOrEmpty( tbCustomerId.Text)?null:tbCustomerId.Text` each time.

Comment: Hehe, if you place this method in a static class, and use the `this` keyword, you could use it like an extension method ;) - Much shorter to write

Comment: you could at least make it an extension method, no?

Comment: Of course you can make an extension method but I don't really like it, especially on null references. Personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not what you directly asked, but one way to achieve what you are trying to do (pass a null value to SQL for a string if the string's value is empty) is use an if-statement to check the length of the string value being passed during the SQL Query parameter assignment (e.g. `Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter", mySqlValue)`):

```cs
if (mySqlValue.Length > 0) {
    SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mySqlValue", mySqlValue);
}
else {
    SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mySqlValue", DBNull.Value);
}
```

where `SqlCommand` is the variable in a `using` statement that utilizes a parameterized SQL Query and a pre-established SQL connection/connection string.

It's not an elegant solution, but it works (and doesn't require that you write an extension method).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return an empty string as null automatically when deserializing json:

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    string sample;
    [JsonProperty("myProperty")]
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return sample; }
        set { sample = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? null : value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Starting with your string

```
string myString = "";
```

Write a method that converts blank to null

```
public static string NullIf(string value)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) { return null; }
    return value;
}
```

Then wrap in the method and call it back with the same syntax you'd expect in SQL

```
NullIf(myString);
```

Comment: OP said they don't want an extension method, and there are already multiple answers that provide extension methods anyway.